# Change SharePoint default date time format to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: sharepoint, datetime-format, regional-settings

How do we change SharePoint default date time format to dd MMM yyyy( e.g., 1 May 2013),

We can change regional setting to change date format but i can not find anything which display month as word.

I am referring following article it seems working except dd MMM yyyy format ( e.g., 1 May 2013). I've notice issue with displaying month in word, other format seem working.

http://sharepointex.blogspot.in/2007/09/how-to-modify-date-format-in-sharepoint.html

Any idea why it month name is not displaying as expected?

Regards,

Answer (score 6):

For Sharepoing 2010 Regional Settings are hidden for the Central Admin site collection. However, you can get to them by typing the url (substitute mysharepointserver:port for your central admin web application).

```
http://mysharepointserver:port/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx
```

Comment: Changed the locale in the link above and all the sites in my web application. Worked for me.. Am I missing anything???

Comment: Works for SharePoint 2013 as well

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to change the format of date& time columns for a SharePoint Site .Here are two options :

1.You can modify the view of the view in SharePoint Designer to format the date &time column . Change the formula to ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),1033,7) .

2.You can Modify the Regional Settings for the site collection .Change the Locale to other countries ,the date format will change automatically for all the existing data &time columns .

I have tried with German and its date &time format is like dd mm yyyy .

Comment: Thanks for your response

1. Solution works if we have few place to change but not for everywhere for example, created and modified date on each add/edit list\library forms

2. we can regional settings but not to specific format dd MMM yyyy

I want to change date time format everywhere in sharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Locale from Site's Regional Settings within Site Administration > Regional settings.

I have tried with SharePoint 2013

Thanks,
Chiranthaka

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need a global site setting; however if you opt for the field by field format, you can format to a specific format by specifying "dd MMM yyyy" explicitly in your XSL.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]) ,1033 ,'dd MMM yyyy')"/>
```

http://afsawaf.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2010-format-view-date-format.html

Good luck!